# C# Unity - How do I make my "PlayerMovement" script and "Use Gravity" checkbox (rigidbody) enable when I click SPACEBAR in game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, user-input

I started making my first game a week ago and I've run into some problems with the coding. Basically, I have made a game where you play as a Ball. The goal is to dodge the obstacles and reach the end of the level.

I've made a respawner that puts the ball at the very beginning of the map whenever you die. My problem is that as soon as the ball has respawned it starts moving again.

What I have done so far to prevent the Ball from moving at the start is that I have DISABLED the Ball's `PlayerMov` script (player movement) and the checkbox "Use Gravity" in the Rigidbody component. So now my Ball is stuck at the start position unable to move.

So what do I need help with? I want the human player to press the spacebar in order for the ball's `PlayerMov` script and "Use Gravity" checkbox (in Rigidbody) to enable. So instead of having the ball immediately move after it has respawned, it will now wait for the human player to press the spacebar before starting.

The script you can see below is my `EnableMovement` script where I attempted to fix this issue. But something's wrong, and I'm not quite sure what it is.

[image: Code error]

Comment: places it in `update()`

Comment: You should post your code in text format here instead of a screenshot of it.

Comment: I correctly embedded the image in your post, although you should still post code *as* code, not an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: My mistake, the property you want to change is not `enabled` for a `Rigidbody`. It is [`IsKinematic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html). Also you probably want to disable collisions too. I've edited my code below.

A simple solution could be to have the physics disabled when the game is run, and enable it when the player presses space. Setting the `Rigidbody.IsKinematic` property to `true` means the `GameObject` won't be affected by physics. That way you don't need to touch the gravity settings or disable the script.

```
Rigidbody _rigidbody;    

void Start() // or could go in the Awake() method depending on your game
{
    _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    TogglePhysics(false);
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        TogglePhysics(true);
    }
}

void TogglePhysics(bool isEnabled)
{
    // IsKinematic needs to be true to disable physics. See the documentation for IsKinematic.
    _rigidbody.IsKinematic = !isEnabled; 
    _rigidBody.detectCollisions = isEnabled;
}

// When respawning, call TogglePhysics(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Lews Therin, when I tried typing out your code I got an error saying 

"Assets/Scripts/EnableMovement.cs(13,35): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Rigidbody' does not contain a definition for `enabled' and no extension method `enabled' of type `UnityEngine.Rigidbody' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

For your info, the ".enabled" in "GetComponent<Rigidbody>().enabled = false;" is marked with a red line.

Thanks in advance,
E.W

Comment: Hey! The code now runs without any errors, however, nothing happens when I click spacebar (I both tried having the physics/scripts enabled and disabled before running the game). Do you think I need to add the "EnableMovement" script (where the code is at) to the Players Inspector? When I drop the script at the player inspector it says "This action will lose the prefab connection. Are you sure you wish to continue?" I have avoided clicking continue until I am certain of the consequences.

Thanks again,
E.W

Comment: Yes, this code assumes the script is attached to the `GameObject` that you want to enable/disable physics for. If you don't want it to break the prefab, attach the script to the prefab (in the `Assets` folder/subfolder where you saved your prefabs) instead of attaching it to the `GameObject` in the inspector (and apply the changes to the prefab so all your instances of the prefab in the inspector are updated).

Comment: Alright I dragged the EnableMovement script onto the Player asset without breaking the prefab. The results are that the player keeps moving no matter if the script/physics are turned off/on. So I tried putting the script directly onto the inspector (which broke the prefab connection). This made the ball just stand still no matter if the physics/script was turned off or on. Afterwards I tried putting the enablemovement script back onto the player asset but now he won't move (assuming it's because I broke the prefab connection previously).

Comment: Small update: The ball might be frozen, but when you click play game I can see the "Is Kinematic" checkbox in Rigidbody being enabled.

Comment: Oh! It worked! I re enabled the gravity and speed. Then I clicked spacebar which disabled the "Is Kinematic". Now everything works, thanks a ton for the help! :)

Comment: Glad to hear you got it figured out :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to place it in `update()` method, so, the script will check every frames if the spacebar was pressed.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) //notice the removing of the ;
    {
        GetComponent<PlayerMov>().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

There was a mistake in your code, when typing this :

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)); //notice the ;
{
    GetComponent<PlayerMov>().enabled = true;
}
```

This is the same thing than :

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    ; //Do nothing
//there is a scope that will be executed
{
    GetComponent<PlayerMov>().enabled = true;
}
```

and this is exactly the same than this :

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
{
    ; //Do nothing
}
//there is a scope that will be executed
{
    GetComponent<PlayerMov>().enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Hey Cid, thanks for your answer. When I type in your code I get two errors:
The first one is "Assets/Scripts/EnableMovement.cs(14,4): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `void', expecting `;', `{', `=>', or `where'"

The second one is "Assets/Scripts/EnableMovement.cs(19,250): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `end-of-file'"

Any solution would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance,
E.W

Comment: Did you replaced the whole content of your script by my above code or did you just replaced the update method?